# Google docs API to get the location index and the timestamp of each character

Tags: google-docs-api

I need to find the location index of all the Characters present in Google document and the time at which the characters were inserted in the document (docs.google.com with doc id)

Please help me finding the Google API for the same.

I am trying the following way today -
Every time you type some character in google docs it raises the following call to google itself-

/save?id=1iz2wfUhHEI8rUq3j2U3GdCtUNjg9zWbGaCmTIrUATNg&sid=3f66d339b8644b95&vc=1&c=1&w=1&flr=0&smv=8&token=AC4w5VgG1zJmVE7TEMTnRVyJWSr83I-VJw%3A1588917639984&includes_info_params=true

In header we have following "bundles" tag -
bundles: [{"commands":[{"ty":"is","ibi":3,"s":"is"}],"sid":"3f66d339b8644b95","reqId":1}]

So in bundles 
"S" is the string you typed (I typed "is")
"ibi" is index of the character where it is inserted in the google docs

I keep building the index map for the entire character in the doc, so looking for some clean solution where i can ask all the index of character in a google document and the time when it was inserted...

Comment: Can you share what you have tried so far? The Google [Docs API exists](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest), I'm not sure if it has methods to access timestamp for character insertion though.

Comment: Do you know the API name for finding the startindex of a character in the google docs ?

Comment: How are you planning to do this? Do you mind describing step by step what you are trying to achieve, and how?

Comment: Updated my explanation above how I am achieving it today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a nearby approach using..
https://docs.google.com/document/d//revisions/load?id=&start=1&end=29

Gives initial timestamp and index

start = start rev
end = end minor rev

Answer (score 1):

There are no methods in the Docs API or in Apps script's DocumentApp  to get the timestamp and index of a character in text.

However you can create a Feature Request in Google Issue Tracker here: https://issuetracker.google.com/

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ftH7FQ5KgySPaIn7SNq6vogCtvIjg6Cibnkig4rQBEU/revisions/load?id=1ftH7FQ5KgySPaIn7SNq6vogCtvIjg6Cibnkig4rQBEU&start=1&end=29